# How can I bind certain properties belonging to a custom control?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, custom-controls

If I have the following control:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl{
    public string MyControlText{
        get { return MyTextBox.Text; } 
        set { MyTextBox.Text = value; }
    }

    public MyControl(){ ... }
}
```

How can I bind to the "MyControlText" property when I place the control on one of my pages, like so:

```
<local:MyControl MyControlText={Binding Path=SomeField} />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the property a dependency property.  The documentation for the DependencyProperty class shows you how to do this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx#